# How to get the actual current controller on $routeChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I have a global routechangesuccess event handler for tracking route changes as "Page Loads" to our analytics platform.

Currently, I am using the current controller name in the routechangesuccess handler to identify a pre-defined set of variables to send to the anlytics engine (ex: homeController -> foo = 1, galleryController -> foo = 2).

However, we also have a controller which uses logic that determine this value dynamically.

Is there any way to get access to the actual controller object from within the $routeChangeSuccess event handler (as opposed to just the controller name), so I can get access to these dynamic values?

Comment: You want the controller instance? The controller constructor? Or the scope associated with that controller?

Comment: I guess it could be either the controller instance, or the controller's active scope, it just needs to be the actual instance for the current route.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get some mileage out of tacking values on to the `state` object. The docs describe this here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects

You can do it as they specify, at config time, or you can add it dynamically, during `$stateChangeStart`, for instance.

```
// Lives in your triggering controller
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
  toState.data.myVar = 'foo';
});

//... later that day

// Lives wherever you want.
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams){
  logToAnalytics(toState.name, toState.data);
});
```

Comment: Oh, you're using ye-olde-faithful vanilla router. My bad. Prolly just upgrade to [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) :) The migration isn't that bad and the nested states are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to access the controller's active scope, I was in a similar situation where I needed to get the scope of the currently loaded controller whenever a route changed.  The solution I found was to get the current scope on the $viewContentLoaded event.  I had a base controller that all my other controllers were nested in like this:

```
<body ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
    <!--Whatever views that get loaded through angular routing are in here-->
</body>
```

In the base controller, I set the current view's scope like so:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
    $scope.currentViewScope = event.targetScope;
});
```

Once this is done, you can access any of the scope properties or functions that are on the current route's scope from the base controller through the $scope.currentViewScope property.  In your case, if the route specific controller dynamically determines the analytics value you want in a scope function like this:

```
$scope.getAnalyticsValue = function() {
   ...
};
```

Then you would be able to get the results of that function on your base controller like this:

```
if ($scope.currentViewScope && $scope.currentViewScope.getAnalyticsValue) {
    var analyticsValue =  $scope.currentViewScope.getAnalyticsValue();
}
```

The caveat here is that you need to make sure that you don't do this until after the view content has been loaded.

It's definitely a little messy, but it worked for me and allowed me to consistently access scope variables and methods from a child scope within a parent scope.